# Why doesn't this object attribute print as a list?

Tags: python

My class definition:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, parent, daughters, edge):
        self.parent = parent
        self.daughters = daughters
        self.edge = edge
        trie.append(self)
        self.index = len(trie) - 1
        trie[parent].daughters.append(self)
```

When I do:

```
    trie = [node(0, [], 0)]
    currentNode = trie[0]
    print('Current Node: ', currentNode.parent, currentNode.daughters, currentNode.edge, currentNode.index)
```

it prints everything correctly except the 'daughters'. Index is an integer, edge is an integer, parent is an integer, but 'daughters' should be a list. Instead it gives me some sort of object syntax:

```
Current Node:  0 [<__main__.node object at 0x100786dd8>] 0 0
```

Why is it having difficulty with passing a list?

Comment: I suspect it's printing a list, and then the `__repr__` of your node object in that list.

Answer (score 1):

It is printing a list you can see the square brackets in the output, `[<__main__.node object at 0x100786dd8>]`, which is a list with 1 node object in it

You can also confirm by looking into the type of that attribute with `type(currentNode.daughters)` e.g. by printing the type out

Comment: Right, but it's supposed to be an empty list (or a list of integers), not a list of objects. I initialized it with '[ ]'. So why is there an object inside?

Comment: @user6309 ...because you `append`ed it?

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thank you. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem , to have a meanningful text instead of <**main**.node object at 0x100786dd8> , you can provide the class with a `__str__` function :

```
class node:
def __init__(self, parent, daughters, edge):
    self.parent = parent
    self.daughters = daughters
    self.edge = edge
    trie.append(self)
    self.index = len(trie) - 1
    trie[parent].daughters.append(self)
def __str__(self):
    return "some string !"
```

Comment: meaningful `__repr__`. Lists call `repr` on their contents.